# Adc Conversion quantization

Tags: java

```
double vDeltaRef, vPlusRef = 10, vMinusRef = 0, q, n, nExp = 3;
     vDeltaRef = vPlusRef - vMinusRef;
     n = Math.pow(2, nExp);
     q = vDeltaRef / n;
     System.out.println(q);
```

the result from the formula is 1.25v
this value:

[image]

How can I translate the obtained result

Comment: Since you know `vPlusRef`, `vMinusRef` and `nExp`, you can always calculate `q` (which is `1.25` in this case). Then, to convert from digital to analog simply multiply the digital value with `q`. And to convert from analog to digital do `(int) Math.floor(analogValue / (double) q);`. For example an analog value of `8.19` would return `6`. Is this what you are asking?

Comment: I want to find the 3-bit value of 1.25
1.25 => corresponding value is  000 .... 111?

Comment: Well, in the above example I gave, `8.19` translates to digital value `6`, which is the 3-bit value `110`.

Comment: I'm so sorry for being careless.
Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know `vPlusRef`, `vMinusRef` and `nExp`, you can always calculate `q` (which is `1.25` in this case).

Then, to convert from digital to analog simply multiply the digital value with `q`. For example the 3-bit value `011`, which is `3` in decimal, will be converted to `3.75` which is the lower bound of the required range `3.75` to `5.00`.

Finally, to convert from analog to digital do:

```
int digitalValue = (int) Math.floor(analogValue / q);
```

For example an analog value of `8.19` would return `6`, which is the 3-bit value `110`.